# How to connect multiple chained dropdown with django-forms-dynamic

Tags: python, django

I have a form with counterparty, object and sections i connected them to each other with django-forms-dynamic package but object not connected to sections

Counterparty connected to object form but sections are not connected to object how can i fix that?

I guess that im wrong with 2 functions in forms.py: section_choices and initial_sections and they`re not connected to objects but dont know how to fix that

forms.py

```
class WorkLogForm(DynamicFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    def object_choices(form):
        contractor_counter = form['contractor_counter'].value()
        object_query = ObjectList.objects.filter(contractor_guid__in=[contractor_counter])
        return object_query

    def initial_object(form):
        contractor_counter = form['contractor_counter'].value()
        object_query = ObjectList.objects.filter(contractor_guid__in=[contractor_counter])
        return object_query.first()

    def section_choices(form):
        contractor_object = form['contractor_object'].value()
        section_query = SectionList.objects.filter(object=contractor_object)
        return section_query

    def initial_sections(form):
        contractor_object = form['contractor_object'].value()
        section_query = SectionList.objects.filter(object=contractor_object)
        return section_query.first()

    contractor_counter = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Контрагент',
        queryset=CounterParty.objects.none(),
        initial=CounterParty.objects.first(),
        empty_label='',
    )

    contractor_object = DynamicField(
        forms.ModelChoiceField,
        label='Объект',
        queryset=object_choices,
        initial=initial_object,
    )

    contractor_section = DynamicField(
        forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField,
        label='Раздел',
        queryset=section_choices,
        initial=initial_sections,
    )
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def create_work_log(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WorkLogForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            work_log = form.save(commit=False)
            work_log.author = request.user
            work_log = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Данные занесены успешно', {'work_log': work_log})
            return redirect('create_worklog')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка валидации')
            return redirect('create_worklog')
  
        form = WorkLogForm(user=request.user, initial=initial)

    return render(request, 'contractor/create_work_log.html', {'form': form})


def contractor_object(request):
    form = WorkLogForm(request.GET, user=request.user)
    return HttpResponse(form['contractor_object'])


def contractor_section(request):
    form = WorkLogForm(request.GET, user=request.user)
    return HttpResponse(form['contractor_section'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer you want but I use HTMX for these things.  Here is a link to their example for this.

https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/

There is also a package plugin called Django-htmx.

You may need to learn HTMX but it is a mature technology, rather simple and reliable.  I am unfamiliar with Django-forms-dynamic